# best way to organise multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and trying to learn how to use dataframes. I read using stock data is a good project to get to grips with them.

So I have found some daily stock data from 1990 to 2010. Each stock has 5 columns,

> Date, Open Price, High Price, Low Price & Close Price

So I am trying to workout what is the best way to organise the data.

Lets say I have data for multiple stocks. Is it best to merge them all into one big dataframe or to stack the dataframes on top each other? Or is there another method I'm missing?

Comment: how are you planning to save it?in sql DB?

Comment: Save in dict :-) what I usually do, and if you want to do some time series ana , just pd.concat(d), you will have a multiple index dataframe , then '

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. I can imagine using `pd.concat` to append them over `axis=0`, so on top of each other and at the same time add a new column called `stock` which indicates to which stock each row belongs.

Comment: `MultiIndex` of (Stock, Date) seems natural, if you have the memory for all of it.

Comment: @anky_91 I have stored the data in SQL Server

Comment: @mHelpMe then you can just `to_sql` and `append`? you have the date already which you can filter for any joins(pull the max date for latest records for example) later on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you have three stocks named `S1`, `S2`, and `S3`, and 
already have a data frame for each one:

```
import pandas as pd

## create some fake data in format described by OP... 
stock_names = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': ['2019-05-05', '2019-05-06'],
  'openp': [100, 110], 'highp': [115, 120], 
  'lowp': [100, 105], 'closep': [110, 120]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': ['2019-05-05', '2019-05-06'],
  'openp': [110, 120], 'highp': [125, 130], 
  'lowp': [110, 115], 'closep': [120, 130]
})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': ['2019-05-05', '2019-05-06'],
  'openp': [120, 130], 'highp': [135, 140], 
  'lowp': [120, 125], 'closep': [130, 140]
})
```

Here's a few ways you could store the data (including the two mentioned by OP).

```
## scenario 1: store the dfs in a list that you can iterate over 
##             (can only access stocks by index, not name) 
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]


## scenario 2: dict of data frames -- just a better version of scenario 1 
##             (access a stock by its name, e.g. `df_dict['S1']`) 
df_dict = dict(zip(stock_names, [df1, df2, df3]))


## scenario 3: single data frame, with 'stock' field to track where rows came from. 
##             (nice bc you can do grouped aggregations easily)
stacked_df = pd.concat(
  [df.assign(stock = stock) for df, stock in zip(df_list, stock_names)])
```

In my experience Scenario 3 is usually (but not always!) the nicest to work with, 
because it plays nice with [`pd.DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.aggregate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) methods. Very convenient if you're doing exploratory data analysis in an interactive shell (see also [the pandas split-apply-combine user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)).

Here's an example of why Scenario 3 can be nice -- straightforward to calculate mean opening and closing price per stock simultaneously (could of course be accomplished in other scenarios, just not using this kind of groupby-aggregate chain).

```
(stacked_df
  .groupby(['stock'])
  .aggregate({'openp': pd.np.mean, 'closep': pd.np.mean}))

##        openp  closep
## stock       
## S1       105     115
## S2       115     125
## S3       125     135
```

You can group by multiple columns too, or group by date, etc., using other aggregation functions of interest.

Comment: `pd.concat` accepts a keys argument, so you could do something like: `pd.concat([df.set_index('date') for df in df_list], keys=stock_names)`

Comment: indeed, nice point! i suspect it's more efficient too. imo the resulting `MultiIndex` can be a little confusing (where the stock name is part of the row index instead of a column) -- tho that is mostly a matter of personal taste i spose